# How to show the last portion of text in TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a `TextView` in which I want to show the last portion of a `String`. Normally if I set a large text in `TextView` the first portion of text will be shown in `TextView`. But my requirement is to show the last portion (Last full stop will be shown to left of `TextView`). I don't know the text size, but it will be large. I have to use single line and I don't want to use ellipses (3 dot).

Answer (score 2):

Check out this,

```
TextView tvTextView;
String text = "YOUR LONG TEXT WILL BE HERE", subString = "",
int textViewWidth = 100;
int numChars;

tvTextView.setText(text);
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
textViewWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels; // you need to subtract paddings and margins if needed
Log.d("textview_width", "width " + textViewWidth + " length " + text.length());

Paint paint = tvTextView.getPaint();
for (numChars = 1; numChars <= text.length(); ++numChars) {
    if (paint.measureText(text, 0, numChars) >= textViewWidth) {

            break;
    }
}
subString = text.substring(text.length() + 1 - numChars, text.length());

    int dots = subString.split("\\.").length * 2;

    if(text.length() <= numChars - 1){

        subString = text;
    }
    else {

        subString = text.substring(text.length() + 1 + dots - numChars, text.length());
    }
    tvTextView.setText(subString);
```